How to prove that all extensions of a pure state are product states?
I tried using the $\rho$ operator for this, and I got nothing. I approached it assuming I have two subsystems $A$ and $B$, both inside their own Hilbert space $H_A$ and $H_B$. And even defined $\rho = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi |$. But at the time of doing the extension, I am at a loss.

What is an "extension of a pure state"?

It's the process of embedding a state defined (pure) on one quantum system into a larger composite quantum system (made by other subsystems)

@mirikubuar Edit the question and put that into maths. I still don't understand.

Do you want to prove that if a density matrix $\sigma$ is pure, then it can be a reduced density matrix only for a product bipartite density matrix?

What exactly are you looking for here?  It seems pretty clear (not too hard to prove; just pick a basis) that if the state of system A and B is entangled, then the trace over the B degrees of freedom leaves a non-pure state, which means the extension of a pure state of A must be a product state. But maybe there are more details about the mathematics of how the embedding of A into A+B is done, in which case those details are relevant and should be added to your post.

@mirikubuar You might try asking here instead: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Also, please spend some time writing your question so that it is clear. Review what you have written, edit it, edit it again, and continue to edit until it is clear.

I think the condition of determining the state of a composite register is the tensorial product of the states.
If you have two independent states,
$\sigma = \sum_{ij} \sigma_{ij} | v_i \rangle \langle v_j | \hspace{1mm}\in D(\mathcal{X})$
$\xi = \sum_{kl} \xi_{kl} | v_k \rangle \langle v_l | \hspace{1mm}\in D(\mathcal{Y})$
The mixed state is
$\rho = \sigma \otimes\xi = \left[ \sum_{ij} \sigma_{ij} | v_i \rangle \langle v_j | \right] \otimes \left[ \sum_{kl} \xi_{kl} | v_k \rangle \langle v_l | \right] = \sum_{ijkl} \sigma_{ij} \xi_{kl} | v_i \rangle \langle v_j | \otimes | v_k \rangle \langle v_l |  $
And if you do the partial trace for example, $\text{Tr}_{\mathcal{Y}} (\rho) = \sigma$, it should help you to show that effectively, $\rho$ is an extension of $\sigma$. Oh, if you have an extension made from two pure states, that new extension is gonna be also a pure state. With this I think you can prove that the extension of a pure state can be written as tensorial products.
